# BackgroundUploader for object as JSON

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to upload some data to a Web API in Windows Phone and the BackgroundUploader class introducted for 8.1 seems to be what I need.  However, I cannot see a way of uploading an object instead of just a file.

My code would look like;

```
var uploader = new BackgroundUploader();
uploader.SetRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
uploader.SetRequestHeader("Authorization",  String.Format("Bearer {0}", _accessToken));
uploader.Method = "POST";

uploader.CreateUpload(APIUri, File);
```

But to change the last line to this;

```
uploader.CreateUpload(APIUri, OBJECT);
```

The OBJECT contains a bunch of info as well as the file as a byte array.  What I am trying to do is convert this object to json for upload.

Does anyone know if this is possible with the BackgroundUploader class?  Previously I have been using HttpClient but this cannot continue the upload when the app is not open which is unacceptable.

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(APIUri, OBJECT);
```

Thanks for any ideas or help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BackgroundUploader` only works with files. If you want to upload additional data with a file then you have 2 options:

1. Add the extra data to a custom header.
2. Include the data in the file.

Yes. both of these options will require server changes to handle this.

Comment: I had thought about adding the data to a header.  I'm not quite sure how to do this but will have a look!  Thanks for confirming.